# ¿Cómo detecto e imprimo los números enteros dentro de una lista?

Tags: python, lista

dada una `lista = [20, 'Maria', 3, True]`

Cómo hago para sacar sólo los números enteros? He hecho este código, pero también me detecta el True, siendo éste un booleano i no un número:

```py
f = []                                                                                                   
s = []

for i in lista:

    try:
        f.append(int(i))
    except ValueError:
        s.append(i)
print('Los números de la lista son:', f)
```

Y el resultado me da 'Los números de la lista son: [20,3,1]

No entiendo porqué me sale el 1.

Alguien puede echarme un cable?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: El booleano `True`, cuando lo conviertes en entero mediante `int()` da lugar al 1 (y si fuera `False` daría 0). Por eso quizás no es buena idea usar `try/except`. Puedes mirar `if type(i) == int`

Answer (score 3):

La siguiente función es una solución general al problema de *¿Cómo detectar los enteros|punto flotante|string en una lista?*

```
def filtrar(lista, tipo):
    salida = []
    for elemento in lista:
        if type(elemento) == tipo:
            salida.append(elemento)
    return salida
```

La función recibe una lista y un tipo (int, float, str). Recorre la lista con un `for` y examina el *tipo* de cada elemento. Si coincide con el parámetro, lo agrega a la salida.

Una versión más compacta, usando comprensión de listas:

```
def filtrar(lista, tipo):
    return [x for x in lista if type(x) == tipo]
```

#### Demo

```
def filtrar(lista, tipo):
    salida = []
    for elemento in lista:
        if type(elemento) == tipo:
            salida.append(elemento)
    return salida

lista_hetero = [1, 2, 3.0, 4.0, "a", "b"]

print(filtrar(lista_hetero, int))
print(filtrar(lista_hetero, float))
print(filtrar(lista_hetero, str))
```

produce:

```
[1, 2]
[3.0, 4.0]
['a', 'b']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar una lista por comprensión

```
A = [20, 'Maria', 3, True]

[x for x in A if type(x) in [int, float]]
```

Te devuelve

```
[20, 3]
```

Observa que la vida es más sencilla cuando utilizas `in` en lugar de `==`.

`==` es una operación binaria, osea es una comparación uno a uno.
`in` es una forma de usar `or` y `==` al mismo tiempo.

En el ejemplo la condición `type(x) in [int, float]` es equivalente a la condición

`type(x) == int or type(x) == float`.

A mi parecer esta forma es más práctica.

Comment: En este caso particular, OP pidió solo números enteros, por lo que con solo incluir float (y ningún otro condicional) no sería una respuesta adecuada (ya que aceptaría números como 3.1, 3.2, etc.). Por mi parte lo haría solo añadiéndole `and x//1==x`

Comment: Cierto. Si quiere cualquier numero racional sería por este medio.